# Docker share a volume on Windows with Docker toolbox

Tags: docker, windows-10, mount, sharing, docker-toolbox

**The goal:**

share project directory on Windows to the container, with docker toolbox

for the testing, I took this php:5.6.15-apache

**What I did:**

I have tried a few recommendations:

1. run with options -v

   ```
   docker run --name=simple2 --rm -v "/c/Users/Admin/pr:/var/www/html" -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -d php:5.6.15-apache
   ```
2. Create a shared directory in default VM

[image]

and mount it inside default docker container

```
   mkdir /home/docker/pr
   mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 pr /home/docker/pr
```

3. Run container with mounting on the shared directory, in this case creates a directory inside docker with name pr

   ```
   docker run -d --name simple2 -it -v /var/www/html:/pr -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -d php:5.6.15-apache


   docker inspect simple2

   "Mounts": [
       {
           "Type": "bind",
           "Source": "/var/www/html",
           "Destination": "/pr",
           "Mode": "",
           "RW": true,
           "Propagation": "rprivate"
       }
   ],
   ```

none of this didn't follow me to the success. I mean none of this steps doesn't share the code between php:5.6.15-apache and Windows

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

docker run --rm --name simple2 -v /home/docker/pr:/var/www/html -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -d php:5.6.15-apache

Comment: Please explain how this answer is different from what the asker tried, and how you think it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just share the root of drive `c:\`

[image]

It's better to restart your default VM then try to run your first command :

`docker run --name=simple2 --rm -v "/c/Users/Admin/pr:/var/www/html" -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -d php:5.6.15-apache`